# Compare previous column value in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

There is a table with below structure:

```
ID  XID   RChange 
1    1     1
2    2     1
3    3     1
4    1     0
5    2     0
6    3     1
```

ID column is an identity column
XID column will have some values repeating
RChange will have either 1 or 0

I need those rows from the table with RChange column value changing from 1 to 0 with same XID

i.e. in the above table, for XID 1 and 2 RChange value has changed from 1 to 0 but for XID 3 it has changed from 1 to 1.

So, I need to write a query which will retrieve

```
ID XID  RChange
4   1     0
5   2     0
```

So, please help me with your ideas.

Answer (score 2):

You have not included a timestamp so I am assuming the `ID` column will determine the order.

```
;WITH byXID AS
(
    SELECT ID, XID, RChange, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY XID ORDER BY ID) rn
    FROM Table1
)
SELECT t1.ID, t1.XID, t1.RChange
FROM byXID t1
INNER JOIN byXID t0 ON t1.XID = t0.XID AND t0.rn = t1.rn - 1
WHERE t1.RChange = 0 AND t0.RChange = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d56f6/2)

Answer (score 0):

This is another approach:

```
SELECT t2.ID, t2.XID, t2.RChange
FROM Table1 t1 JOIN Table1 t2
        ON t1.XID = t2.XID
WHERE t1.RChange = 1 AND t2.RChange = 0
```

**[Sql fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d56f6/4)** (Thanks @Ic. for the fiddle)